# jQuery how to handle the request answer in jQuery Validator?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
email: {
    required: true,
    email: true,
    remote: {
        url: "/user/check_email",
        type: "post",
        data: {
            email: function () {
                return $("#email").val();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the server returns `1` or `0`, but how in jQuery validator I can handle that result?

Comment: The data response you get back is just 1 or 0? I'm guessing that's true or false, so trigger your "validated" (whatever you have) function if it's 1, and "fail" function if it's 0.

Comment: so there are no built-in handle function for this? also the result is displayed in the label, it shows 1 or 0

Answer (score 1):

```
        email: {
                required: true,
                  email: true,
                  remote: {
                    url: "/user/check_email",
                    type: "post",
                    data: {
                      email: function() {
                        return $( "#email" ).val();
                      }
                    },
                    success: function(msg) {

                        alert(msg);

                    }
                  }
            }
```

I've found it, just add a success function...